# Spring data mongodb: A way to insert or update a list of documents (upsertAll?)

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

`MongoOperations` has methods like `save` that will either insert or update the document and we also have `insertAll` that will add all documents in the list.

Is there a way where I will provide a list of documents (with id) and based of if they are present or not, it should either update or insert respectively? May be an combination of `save` and `insertAll` say `upsertAll`

Comment: Do you mind trying `MongoRepository`?

Answer (score 0):

The MongoRepository of Spring has the function: [*save(Iterable)*](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/MongoRepository.html#insert-java.lang.Iterable-), which saves all the elements the Iterable contains.

I recommend to take a look at the Repository. It simplifies a lot of database stuff (in my opinion).